# Dual monitor VGA/DVI not working after switching PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, splitter

I have a problem with my second monitor. My primary monitor is connected via VGA->DVI and my second via a DVI both plugged into one DVI port with a dual cable. I have had this setup for over 2 years - working fine.

This morning I wanted to check an other PC so I took out the dual cable and put it into the test PC. After the test I plugged it back in. However, now only my primary (VGA) monitor works, my secondary (DVI) light is flashing until login screen; then tells me “ No signal”. OS is Windows 7.

Monitors are Acer X183H (primary, VGA) and Gateway HX1953L (secondary, DVI).

Would anybody have an idea whats up? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which OS???????

Comment: Windows, I will also adjust this in the main post - excuse me.

Comment: Is the screen detected in display properties?  It may not be activated.

Comment: Yes it is, I actually checked all those things. I can also move different windows to that display if I extend it.. but it just doesnt show

Comment: Did you try to swap the cables and check if it works?

Comment: Both monitors work solely, both monitors also work on other PC's.